# python threading, confirming responses before moving to next line

Tags: python, multithreading, google-api, io, python-requests

Recently I have been working to integrate google directory, calendar and classroom to work seamlessly with the existing services that we have.
I need to loop through 1500 objects and make requests in google to check something. Responses from google does take awhile hence I want to wait on that request to complete but at the same time run other checks.

```py
    def __get_students_of_course(self, course_id, index_in_course_list, page=None):
        print("getting students from gclass ", course_id, "page ", page)
        # self.__check_request_count(10)
        try:
            response = self.class_service.courses().students().list(courseId=course_id,
                                                                    pageToken=page).execute()
            # the response must come back before proceeding to the next checks
            course_to_add_to = self.course_list_gsuite[index_in_course_list]
            current_students = course_to_add_to["students"]
            for student in response["students"]:
                current_students.append(student["profile"]["emailAddress"])
                self.course_list_gsuite[index_in_course_list] = course_to_add_to
            try:
                if "nextPageToken" in response:
                    self.__get_students_of_course(
                        course_id, index_in_course_list, page=response["nextPageToken"])
                else:
                    return
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return
        except Exception as e:
            print((e))
```

And I run that function from another function

```py
    def __check_course_state(self, course):
        course_to_create = {...}
        try:
            g_course = next(
                (g_course for g_course in self.course_list_gsuite if g_course["name"] == course_to_create["name"]), None)

            if g_course != None:
                index_2 = None
                for index_1, class_name in enumerate(self.course_list_gsuite):
                    if class_name["name"] == course_to_create["name"]:
                        index_2 = index_1

                self.__get_students_of_course(
                    g_course["id"], index_2) # need to wait here
                students_enrolled_in_g_class = self.course_list_gsuite[index_2]["students"]

                request = requests.post() # need to wait here
                students_in_iras = request.json()
                students_to_add_in_g_class = []
                for student in students["data"]:
                    try:
                        pass
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                        students_to_add_in_g_class.append(
                            student["studentId"])

                if len(students_to_add_in_g_class) != 0:
                  pass
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

I need to these tasks for 1500 objects.
Although they are not related to each other. I want to move to the next object in the loop while it waits for the other results to come back and finish.
Here is how I tried this with threads:

```py
    def create_courses(self):
        # pool = []
        counter = 0
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as excecutor:
            results = excecutor.map(
                self.__check_course_state, self.courses[0:5])
```

The problem is when I run it like this I get multiple SSL errors and other errors and as far as I understand, as the threads themselves are running, the requests never wait to finish and move to the next line hence I have nothing in the request object so it throws me errors?
Any Ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ssl error occurs her because i was reusing the http instance from google api lib. `self.class_service` is being used to send a request while waiting on another request. The best way to handle  this is to create instances of the `service` on every request.